# adding winform user control event in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am learning c# at the moment.

I have setup a winform user control (called aUC) with 1 button (called simpleButton1)
in vb I can do the following.

```
dim aUC1 as aUC = new aUC()

'load user control to form
Me.controls.clear()
Me.controls.Add(aUC1)

' attach button event
AddHandler aUC1.simpleButton1.Click, AddressOf aUCButton_Click
```

so I try to do the same on c#

```
aUC aUC1 = new aUC();

' load user control to form
this.Controls.Clear();
this.Controls.Add(aUC1);

aUC1.simpleButton1.Click += aUCBtn_Click;
```

when I compile I get

```
aUC.simpleButton1 is inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I notice when I look at the designer code on user control

in vb it says

```
Friend WithEvents SimpleButton1 As DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton
```

in c# it says

```
private DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton simpleButton1;
```

when I change from private to public on user control design generated code it works ok.

I just wondering if this standard practice in c# to hook user control event on main form is to change the control from private to public; or there is a better way/best practice for c#, I prefer not to changing the code on the design generated code in case I accidentally stuff it up.

Thank you.

Regards

- Haris -

Comment: The user control should expose an event for when its button is clicked, not allow other classes to reach into it and attach events to its internal set of controls

Comment: Hi Caius,

Thank you for the pointer, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Caius,

I create a button click call back on the user control and expose it public event

```
public partial class aUC : UserControl
{
    public EventHandler aUCBtn_Click;

    public aUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (aUCBtn_Click != null)
            aUCBtn_Click(sender, e); // send event to public event
    }
}
```

and on the main form consume that public event

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    aUC aUC1 = new aUC();
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.Controls.Add(aUC1);

    aUC1.aUCBtn_Click += aUC1_Click; // hook to user control event                       
}

private void aUC1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("btn click");
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as You want to access a button from another class you should change the access modifier to public from the designer there is no other way

but I will advise you to learn WPF instead of Winforms